# Incrementing numerical value and changing string in SQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, replace

I have a database that has stored values in a complicated, serialized array where one component is a string and another is the length of the characters of the string, in this format:

> s:8:"test.com"

Where "s" holds the character length of the string in the quotations.

I would like to change the string from "test.com" to "testt.com", and I'm using the following statement in SQL:

> UPDATE table SET row=(REPLACE (row, 'test.com','testt.com'))

However, this breaks the script in question, because it doesn't update the character length in the "s" preceding the string where "test.com" is stored.

I was wondering if there is a query I can use that would replace the string, and then also increment the value of this "s" preceding to where the replacement occurs, something like this:

> UPDATE table SET row=(REPLACE (row, 's:' number 'test.com','s:' number+1 'testt.com'))

Does anyone know if this kind of query is even possible?

Comment: That is why you should never store multipe information in one column. Please divide that information in 2 columns of determine the length of the string on the fly.

Comment: Hey juergen, it isn't really my script, and I second you on the fact that this has been put together very poorly, however, I have to find a way to make it work without changing the structure of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table set row = concat('s:',length('testt.com'),':"testt.com"');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change exact string, then use exact query -

```
UPDATE table SET row = 's:9:"testt.com"' WHERE row = 's:8:"test.com"';
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is a "[serialized string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)".

If there are multiple strings to be replaced, it might be easier to create a script to handle this.

In PHP, it goes something like this:

```
$searchfor = serialize('test.com');
$replaceby = serialize('testt.com');

// strip last semicolon from serialized string
$searchfor = trim($searchfor,';');
$replaceby = trim($replaceby,';');

$query = "UPDATE table SET field = '$replaceby' WHERE field = '$searchfor';";
```

This way, you can create an exact query string with what you need.
Do fill in the proper code for db connection if necessary.